# redhat enterprise 6.1 Linux compatible softwares

Tags: linux, redhat, server

I am planning to install my j2EE, spring rest based application on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6.1. I want to know about the software version which is compatible. I am not sure whether all the new versions are compatible in REL 6.1.

The list of software's I need to install are

- J2EE
- Apache Tomcat
- SpringRest
- MySQL

Answer (score 1):

The RHEL 6.1 can easily be updated for the latest versions of Java, Tomcat. For the latest MySQL, if there are dependencies not present in RHEL 6.1 then you could try either adding or updating them (using yum or building from source).

1. J2EE: Download from Oracle Java SDK download page [I believe you want JDK since the J2EE dependencies would be provided by Tomcat such as Servlet etc]
2. Apache Tomcat: Download the binaries from the tomcat apache website [http://tomcat.apache.org/]. That should be enough to get you started. If later on you would like to use openssl or apache portable runtime then that is easily setup as well. The tomcat documentation has useful documentation to set it up.
3. SpringRest: I believe you are referring to the java archives for it. You can use Maven to download the necessary dependencies or use Spring Boot (https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) or search Google for the many examples of bundling Spring dependencies with your application.
4. For MySQL: refer to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html